# How to get the name of a folder name separated by an underscore into a value in batch?

Tags: batch-file

Okay, I am trying to get the name of a folder as a value in batch. The folder looks like this:

**John_1**

I am trying to only get the first part of the name the **John** part which is separated with an underscore.

Anyone got any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most string processing in batch, the `FOR /F` command enables you to do this, with the use of the `delims` argument.

```
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ("john_1") do set "name=%%a"
```

Now the part you want is in the `%name%` variable.

Usually you have the string to parse in a variable and not source, though.  To run the above with a variable, you can `echo` the variable.

```
set sz=John_1
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ('echo %sz%') do set "name=%%a"
```

Finally, if for any reason you want to get the second part of the string, `FOR` can allocate another variable to hold it by using the `tokens=` argument.

```
set sz=John_1
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%a in ('echo %sz%') do ( set "name=%%a" & set "number=%%b" )
```

`FOR` is one of the most powerful commands in the batch language.  Run `help for` to see the full list of options available.

Comment: you need something like `"tokens=1,*`" to use the second variable `%%b`

Comment: as @Stephan suggests, I would `1,*` instead of `1,2`, so the second part doesn't get split up if it contains another underscore